# Implement while file >> event with custom classes in C++

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, ifstream

I've to read a binary file coming from a data acquisition system. The binary file I want to read is made of many blocks, each of them starts with a specific tag, let's say they are all TIME in the first part, then all VOLT.

To do this I've created many different classes, the base class containing the file is the following:

```cpp
class MyFile
{
public:
    // many methods...
private:
    std::ifstream in_;
};
```

I have done the overload of the operators >> and <<, I'm able to write something like:

```cpp
MyFile file("filename.dat");
MyTimeEvent tEvent;
MyVoltEvent vEvent;
file >> tEvent;
cout << tEvent << endl;
// file >> tEvent; as many times as I know the TIME blocks are in this specific file.
file >>vEvent;
...
```

what I want to achieve is something like this:

```cpp
MyFile file("filename.dat");
MyTimeEvent tEvent;

while (file >> tEvent)
{
    // do stuff...
}
// Now I'm sure next block is a VOLT block.
```

With the code I have, the compiler says me:

```
error: value of type 'MyFile' is not contextually convertible to 'bool'
```

What do I have to implement? Is it possible?

Comment: You seem to have implement operator overloading already and you seem to be familiar with the concept. So, in order for a class instance to be used in a boolean context, are you aware that the class needs to implement an `operator bool` overload? Do you know how to implement this overload?

Comment: @sam is that really necessary? i know that's how iostreams work but im not clear if his file class is an iostream.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I didn't know I had to implement also the `operator bool` overload, so thanks, I'll give it a look. But still what I don't get is: how the call (or better say cast?) to bool is performed when I write `file >> event`?

Comment: `MyFile`'s `in_` a very cromulant member for forwarding the overloaded operator to, @NeilButterworth.

Comment: check how streams are doing that: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: @MatteoBrini it's called just as `if(file)` (normally `file>>x` return `file` itself, in your case it can also just return a `bool`, despite uncommon)

Comment: @NeilButterworth the class `MyClass` is not a iostream. I'm still not that much familiar with it.

Comment: It's not performed for a mere `file >> event`. But, the shown error message already indicates that your `>>` overload returns `*this`, an instance of this class, and when this gets evaluated in a boolean context magic happens.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that clarifies. Thanks.